# Замена Dll в Linux + java

Tags: java, linux, dll, library

Всем привет. Скажите пожалуйста, какую замену можно придумать оконному DLL на Linux + java.

Если кому интересен полностью процесс работы с библиотекой: запуск программы --> динамически подгрузить все "библиотеки" из папки "addons" --> потом программа вытаскивает кое-какой массив определённых данных, заложенный в каждую библиотеку --> в любой момент программа может вызвать метод любой библиотеки под названием "execute" и работать дальше.

Comment: а на чем будут написаны библиотеки? если на java, то ничего особенного писать не надо. если папка addons будет в `CLASSPATH`, то стандартный `ClassLoader` отлично все загрузит.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman А чего он загрузит-то? Чтобы что-то загрузить одного classpath мало, надо знать название класса, который надо грузить, А addons-ы это как раз заранее неизвестные классы. Так что надо придумывать сканер и/или реестр addon-ов..

Comment: Для java придумано некоторое количество plugin framework-ов разной степени сложности. Погуглите java plugin library|framework.

Comment: @Sergey просканировать директорию не сложно. В принципе можно написать свой ClassLoader для такой цели - это не сложно.